# Project Euler Number 10 in Haskell, Can't Find the Bug

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner to Haskell and I'm having trouble with [Project Euler Problem 10](http://projecteuler.net/problem=10). Here's what I have:

```
primes :: Integral a => [a]
primes = filter isPrime [1,3..]

isPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPrime 1 = False
isPrime n = not $ any isDivisibleBy [2..maxTry]
    where isDivisibleBy x = n `mod` x == 0
          maxTry = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n

solution :: Integral a => a
solution = sum $ takeWhile (<2000000) primes

main = putStrLn $ show solution
```

When I run this, I get 142913828920. Project Euler says that that is incorrect. This is baffling me because I successfully used the same definitions for `primes` and `isPrime` in Problem 7, which was to find the 10001st prime. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would question the line

```
primes = filter isPrime [1,3..]
```

since 2 is a prime.

Comment: And 1 is not a prime number, unless you are [the world's most elite hacker](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298814/goofs)

Comment: I hope the isPrime will filter out 1.  But why 2 is explicitly excluded I can't understand.  And I'm pretty sure it's the problem...

Comment: Oh, I had missed that explicit check. I wonder how he got the 10001st prime correctly though.

Comment: @missingno:  The 10001st prime was right because both 1 & 2 weren't in the list.  Had it asked for the first prime, OP would've been wrong but after that case, the rest will be correct.